# Heroku fails in command line because of logic for home diretcory

Tags: ruby, heroku, command-line-interface, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to intsall Heroku CLI in my Windows 8. It installs with no errors but I realized it has silently failed to create the .heroku folder under C:\Users{username}\.heroku

It seems the issue is that Heroku command line program fails to retreive the correct heroku home folder. It is currently using H: for that (I have no idea why?).

```
C:\Windows\system32>heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
Authentication successful.
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       No such file or directory - H: (Errno::ENOENT)
    Command:     heroku login
    Version:     heroku/toolbelt/3.41.3 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3
    Error ID:    5846017fa2064f07b34620b3dbfb1b4f


    More information in H:/.heroku/error.log

No such file or directory - H:
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `each'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
C:/Users/aidins/.heroku/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:457:in `error_log'
C:/Users/aidins/.heroku/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:451:in `styled_error'
C:/Users/aidins/.heroku/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:39:in `rescue in start'
C:/Users/aidins/.heroku/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:19:in `start'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in `<main>'
No such file or directory - H:
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `each'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
C:/Users/aidins/.heroku/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/updater.rb:98:in `autoupdate'
C:/Users/aidins/.heroku/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Here's how it determines the home folder: https://github.com/fastcatch/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/helpers.rb#L9

Comment: that is not how my source code looks like. This is the version in my box:  def home_directory
      if running_on_windows? && RUBY_VERSION == '1.9.3'
        # https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10126
        Dir.home.force_encoding('cp775')
      else
        Dir.home
      end
    end

Comment: It worked when I replaced that line with existing code. But it breaks when it auto upgrades. I had to comment out the autoupgrade line to avoid it. it is definitely a bug that they just fixed but not released.